# HTTPS GET request to https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me

Tags: php

ok, here's a snippet of my code

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'));
$plus = new Google_PlusService($client);

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
} else {
    $_SESSION['auth_token'] = $client->authenticate();
}
```

and now I've got the $_SESSION['auth_token'] which contains something like

```
{"access_token":"ya29.AHESblablablabalbalbalbagTUI4-MfZvwtb6A","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"id_token":"blablablabalbalbalba.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwiY2lkIjoiNzAzNTg5ODA3MjMxLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiYXpwIjoiNzAzNTg5ODA3MjMxLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiNzAzNTgblablablabalbalbalbaRlbnQuY29tIiwiaGQiOiJnZW9mbGV4LmNvbS5teSIsInZlcmlmaWVkX2VtYWlsIjoidHJ1ZSIsImVtYWlsX3blablablabalbalbalbaFzei00N25nN3VoLU5NUmh3IiwiYXRfaGFzaCI6IllEeC13UXN6LTQ3bmc3dWgtTk1SaHciLCJpYXQiOjEzNzQ1NjA1NDcsImV4cCI6MTM3NDU2NDQ0N30.ek1FX-pY8BdaI8sDhA0rwmiIDyBV6pHPvBi-l7BxDJCR-YoDQGFN8y-kA1xg-vmoReiVCwhvQhHK__jc-xFSLfJDLbwk-UGyRKu_O7ZCaSviP7WupexIYvLGCyvgLBdjG3K7UIcq0o3L15mQPvQJr9LA7325gwEOZ12Pc1lAHKw","refresh_token":"1\/Y7oilVvUUutfkKMDfblablablabalbalbalbaE","created":1374560847}
```

my question is, how do I get the user's email? i know you can just call

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=youraccess_token
```

but is that the 'official' way to get the users's email? because from here https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#exchangecode it says

The Access Token that your application received during the authentication flow with Google can be used to obtain additional profile information about the user. Please be advised that Google is modifying the behavior of the different endpoints to simplify their usage. We currently recommend the following based on existing behavior. If you are using Login with Google+, you should always retrieve user profile information from the People API by sending an HTTPS GET request to https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me using your Access Token to authenticate the request.

So i guess the best way is to perform HTTPS GET request to googleapis.com.. but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone lead the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Google_Oauth2Service object (put it under the $plus initialization), like:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$plus = new Google_PlusService($client);
$oauth2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($client);
```

and after succesfully authenticating the client use:

```
$userInfo = $oauth2->userinfo->get();
$email = $userInfo['email'];
```

Comment: I did that, but before that I need to add require_once "google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php"; right? but after that I got this error '
Fatal error: Class 'Google_TokeninfoServiceResource' not found '. In fact when I tried to run the index.php example in google-api-php-client/examples/userinfo/ it returns the same error

Comment: ok got it. your answer is correct. the error was because of the latest google-api-php-client file (version 0.6.3). had to downgrade to version 0.6.2  to make it work. thanks

Comment: How about create circle or add people to circle? It must to use `Google_Service_PlusDomains` class instead of `Google_Service_Oauth2` class? I also got this error when I used `Google_Service_PlusDomains`, like that: 
`$this->google = new \Google_Service_PlusDomains($this->client);
$this->google->people->get('me'`